# Local Storage isn't working

Tags: javascript, storage, local

My code still works as usually but the local storage doesn't work at all. It says in the console however that everything is fine. The goal is to save the inputted text into the clientInfo variable so that the info stays after refresh. When i refresh though it doesn't save at all. This is my first time using local storage so maybe I'm missing something obvious. Any help would be AMAZING

```
    let message = '';
let student;
let question;
var i;
let security;
let input;
let returned = false;
let late = false;
let clientInfo;
const libraryAccess = document.getElementById('library');
const user = document.getElementById('user');
function signIn() {
   this.render = function(dialog){
       var winW = window.innerWidth;
       var winH = window.innerHeight;
       var dialogoverlay = document.getElementById('dialogoverlay');
       var dialogbox = document.getElementById('dialogbox');
       dialogoverlay.style.display = "block";
       dialogoverlay.style.height = winH+"px";
       dialogbox.style.left = (winW/2) - (550 * .5)+"px";
       dialogbox.style.top = "100px";
       dialogbox.style.display = "block";
       document.getElementById('dialogboxhead').innerHTML = "Type your first name to see your info:";
       document.getElementById('dialogboxbody').innerHTML = `<input type="text" id="input">`;
       document.getElementById('dialogboxfoot').innerHTML = '<button onclick="alert.ok()" id="sign">Sign In</button>';
       const input = document.getElementById('input');
       const signButton = document.getElementById('sign');
       function signClick() {
         signButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
               security = input.value;
               secure(); // calling secure function here because otherwise the function wont run properly if I place it elsewhere
         });
       }
       signClick();
   }
this.ok = function(){
  document.getElementById('dialogbox').style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById('dialogoverlay').style.display = "none";
}
}
var alert = new signIn();

user.addEventListener('click', () => {
   alert.render();
});
//Custom Function that replaces document.write with a better alternative
const print = (message) => {
  var outputDiv = document.getElementById('output');
  outputDiv.innerHTML = message;
}

// These are the categories
const getReport = (student) => {
  let report = `<h1 class="titleName" id="name"> ${student.name} </h1>`;
  `<ol class="lists">`
  report += `<li class="clientLi"> MemberShip: ${student.memberShip} </li>`;
  report += `<li class="clientLi"> MemberSince: ${student.memberSince} </li>`;
  report += `<li class="clientLi"> Points: ${student.points} </li>`;
  report += `<li class="clientLi"> Checking: $${student.checking} </li>`;
  report += `<li class="clientLi"> Debts: ${student.debts} </li>`;
  report += `<li class="clientLi"> Savings: $${student.savings + parseFloat(student.OuncesofSilver * 17.22) + parseFloat(student.goldGrams * 43.02)} </li>`;
  report += `<li class="clientLi"> Ounces of Silver: ${student.OuncesofSilver} </li>`;
  report += `<li class="clientLi"> Books Due: ${student.booksDue} </li>`;
  report += `<li class="clientLi"> GoldGrams: ${student.goldGrams} </li>`;
  `</ol>`
  return report;
}
// Alerts for when something goes above or below certain criteria
const notify = (urgent) => {

  library.addEventListener('click', () => {
      window.location = "library/library.html";
  });

}
//local data
var securityName = '';
 var localData = {
 clientName: 'luke',
 clientName2: 'julie',
 clientName3: 'brendon'
},
data;
 //set Fake local data
 localStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify( localData ));

 //get localstorage
 var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localData'));

 //check if data is valid
 if (data != null && typeof data != 'undefined'){
   secure(securityName, data); //call the function passing parameters
 }else{
   window.alert('localStorage is empty');
 }

 function secure() {
   var message = '';
   if (security !== null || security !== '' || security !== undefined) {
       //ADD YOUR CODE FOR SECURITY HERE - FOR TESTING PURPOSES IT WAS REMOVED.
       if (security === 'luke') {
         clientInfo = data.clientName;
         if (clientInfo === 'luke') {
           var i = 0;
           notify(student);
           message = getReport(students[0]);
           print(message);
         }
       }
       if (security === 'julie') {
         clientInfo = data.clientName2;
         if (clientInfo === 'julie') {
           var i = 1;
           notify(student);
           message = getReport(students[1]);
           print(message);
         }
       }
       if (security === 'brendon') {
         clientInfo = data.clientName3;
         if (clientInfo === 'brendon') {
           var i = 2;
           notify(student);
           message = getReport(students[2]);
           print(message);
         }
       } else {
         clientInfo = '';
         if (clientInfo === '') {

         }
       }
   }
 }

 localStorage.removeItem('clientName');
 localStorage.removeItem('clientName2');
 localStorage.removeItem('clientName3');
print(message);
print(message);
```

Comment: if in your site you hit F12, navigate to Application, open LocalStorage, it is empty?

Comment: and you say "When i refresh though it doesn't save at all", how do you discovered that, what do you expect to see, it need to show something on the page? Could you add just the relevant code here, it would be much better to help

Comment: Local storage has the right data inside it. I could give you all the code but there is a lot

Comment: No, the idea is not the whole code, just the relevant part, where you try to get the localStorage value and where you want to use it. The code that doesn't have anything about localStorage can be removed from the question to avoid extensive code

Comment: Sorry, I just included the other code because I thought I could be another issue since the local storage seemed fine

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you shouldn't post your whole code. If you need to do so, your question is likely too broad. It's much easier to get a good answer if you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

well, testing here, I saw no problem getting the localStorage value.

I only saw that you have a function called `secure()` that you never call, so it never checks anything... so I made some adjustments and it seems to be working fine.

see the code below: (please, keep in mind that StackOverflow doesn't allow localStorage, so, here it will throw an error).

And here is a fiddle to check it working:  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wjPNwo

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var securityName = '';
  var localData = {
  clientName: 'luke',
  clientName2: 'julie',
  clientName3: 'brendon'
  };
  //set Fake local data
  localStorage.setItem('localData', JSON.stringify( localData ));

  //get localstorage 
  var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('localData'));

  //check if data is valid
  if (data != null && typeof data != 'undefined'){
    secure(securityName, data); //call the function passing parameters
  }else{
    window.alert('localStorage is empty');
  }

  function secure(security, data) { 
    var message = '';
    if (security !== null || security !== '' || security !== undefined) {
        //ADD YOUR CODE FOR SECURITY HERE - FOR TESTING PURPOSES IT WAS REMOVED.
    }
    message = 'the data stored in localStorage is on the console log, open it with F12 to debug';
    console.log(data);
    document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = message + '<br><br>' +
      data.clientName+'<br>'+
      data.clientName2+'<br>'+
      data.clientName3+'<br>' ;
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I may have mislead your answer because I didn't provide the full code. I edited my original answer so now the full code is there. I included your code anyways and it is still acting the same. My suspicion is that it has something to do with how I am calling the secure function. I'm not sure what though. I did have the full code at first but someone asked me to change it so it was smaller and I shouldve just not listened to them. Thats my bad

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem. I needed to put the security variable into local storage because after the refresh the variable would be undefined and the clientInfo variable was based off of that variable.